# The draw rectangle is not in the same place as the texture

Tags: c#, xna

This is resulting in the collisions with other objects and not working correctly,

I feel it may have something to do with how we are rotating the sprite for the player, below is the code we are using for the rotation

```
#region draw player

        if (player.facing == 4)

            spriteBatch.Draw(player.txr, player.drawRect, null, Color.White, 1.5708f, new Vector2(player.drawRect.Width / 2, player.drawRect.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        else if (player.facing == 3)

            spriteBatch.Draw(player.txr, player.drawRect, null, Color.White, 4.712389f, new Vector2(player.drawRect.Width / 2, player.drawRect.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        else if (player.facing == 1)

            spriteBatch.Draw(player.txr, player.drawRect, null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(player.drawRect.Width / 2, player.drawRect.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        else if (player.facing == 2)

            spriteBatch.Draw(player.txr, player.drawRect, null, Color.White, 3.14593f, new Vector2(player.drawRect.Width / 2, player.drawRect.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        else if (player.facing == 5)

            spriteBatch.Draw(player.txr, player.drawRect, null, Color.White, 0.785398163f, new Vector2(player.drawRect.Width / 2, player.drawRect.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        else if (player.facing == 6)

            spriteBatch.Draw(player.txr, player.drawRect, null, Color.White, 2.094395102f, new Vector2(player.drawRect.Width / 2, player.drawRect.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        else if (player.facing == 7)

            spriteBatch.Draw(player.txr, player.drawRect, null, Color.White, 3.839724354f, new Vector2(player.drawRect.Width / 2, player.drawRect.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        else if (player.facing == 8)

            spriteBatch.Draw(player.txr, player.drawRect, null, Color.White, 5.497787144f, new Vector2(player.drawRect.Width / 2, player.drawRect.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        #region DEBUG
        //spriteBatch.Draw(Door.txr, player.drawRect, Color.White);
        //spriteBatch.Draw(Door.txr, player1.drawRect, Color.White);
        //spriteBatch.Draw(Door.txr, player2.drawRect, Color.White);
        //spriteBatch.Draw(Door.txr, player3.drawRect, Color.White);
        #endregion
```

Comment: user `MathHelper.ToRadians(90)` to rotate, degrees are more understandable than radians.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a sprite batch will only render your sprite in that rotation. The collision box you have for your player and how you handle it is a separate issue. You have to transform your player collision box with the same rotation as you are drawing.